# What might cause a connection issue with Spark external shuffle service?

Tags: apache-spark, shuffle, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm running a Spark job on dataproc 1.4. with external shuffle service.

Some details to follow up on the comments :

- The cluster doesn't use preemptible VMs
- Autoscaling is off on this cluster and no manual scale down happened.

The job fails with the error below.

What might be the cause ?

```
org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Connection from xxx.internal/10.81.0.46:7337 closed
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:485)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:64)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:435)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:441)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1394)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:417)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection from xxx.internal/10.81.0.46:7337 closed
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.channelInactive(TransportResponseHandler.java:146)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelInactive(TransportChannelHandler.java:108)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:81)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelInactive(IdleStateHandler.java:277)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:81)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelInactive(TransportFrameDecoder.java:178)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1405)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:901)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:818)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 more
```

**edit** August, 21

It seems the error below is in fact a consequence of this one (7337 is the default port of the external shuffle service). It reinforces the hypothesis of @dagang : the Spark shuffle service may be overloaded.

```
"Connection to xxx:7337 has been quiet for 120000 ms while there are outstanding requests. Assuming connection is dead; please adjust spark.network.timeout if this is wrong."
```

The number of partitions is already minimized. To give an idea, there are 30,000 partitions and the cluster has 100 nodes.

So I'm thinking about 3 ways to mitigate the issue

1. Adding more nodes in the cluster, so each shuffle service will have fewer work to do
2. Stopping using the external shuffle service (as suggested here : https://cloud.google.com/architecture/hadoop/migrating-apache-spark-jobs-to-cloud-dataproc)
3. Increasing the configuration of `spark.network.timeout`

What do you think ?

Comment: Repeatable or sporadic?

Comment: Did you scale down the cluster? Is there pre-emptable VMs in the cluster?

Comment: See https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/support/spark-job-tuning#shuffle_fetch_failures

Comment: When connection is closed, it's most likely due firewall. try open in/out on 10.81.0.46:7337.

Answer (score 0):

Clusters with preemptible VMs or an autoscaling policy may receive `FetchFailedException` when workers are preempted or removed before they finish serving shuffle data to reducers.

Possible causes and fixes:

- Preemptible worker VMs were reclaimed or non-preemptible worker VMs were removed by the autoscaler. Solution: Use [Enhanced Flexibility Mode](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/flex) to make secondary workers safely preemptible or scalable.
- Executor or mapper crashed due to OutOfMemory error. Solution: increase the memory of executor or mapper.
- The Spark shuffle service may be overloaded. Solution: decrease the number of job partitions.

See more details in this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/support/spark-job-tuning#shuffle_fetch_failures).

Comment: Do you think it would be effective for secondary workers to send all shuffle data to the external shuffle services of primary workers to eliminate lost data upon node loss?

Comment: Yes, that's the recommended solution.

Comment: Is there an option for doing this? I only know of the extended flexibility mode and the normal shuffle mode, however no mode where shuffle files are sent only to primary workers. (Extended flexibility writes shuffles to hdfs rather than individual nodes, resulting in additional complexity). Thanks!

Comment: EFM has two options: HCFS and primary worker. Check the doc.

Comment: Oh wow this is awesome! I dont think it was available when EFM first came out, but it's amazing. Thank you!